# Bootstrap tab panel active

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have wasted ridiculous amount of time behind tab-content but can't figure a way out. This is my view [code here](http://pastebin.com/Zj9BFpg2).

But when I click on tab and try to switch tab panel, all of tab pane goes to display:none as I have added $('.tab-content div').hide(). But when I tried to show the panel, it didn't work.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: here is it [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLk5djzh/)

Comment: lol can't you at least copy some parsed html from you page no just paste the php in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the # in the links

```
<a href="#<?php echo urlencode($course->courseCode);?>"
```

and to urlencode the id on the tab

```
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo urlencode($item->courseCode);?>">
```

Comment: I have added this but still all of the panels are having display:none after click event fires

Comment: what do you want to do with the click event?